# Get a JSON response from JIRA webservice in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, rest

I am attempting to access the JIRA REST webservice using iOS. I have managed to get the requests to work, but the response is not JSON.  I get a response with a session id and everything from the login request that comes before this one, and this request returns a similar response, but the data coming back that is suppose to be JSON but looks like : <61737369 616e2e6e 65742f73 65637572 652f7072 (continues for several lines)>.  I have made the same requests with JMeter and it gets returned a JSON string, but this request in iOS does not.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://company.atlassian.net/rest/
           api/2/project"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type" ];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    //Encoded authorization header
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:
        [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse 
           *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){ }];
```

I have attempted to manipulate the Content-Type trying random different things, but none have worked.  Any ideas on how to get it to return JSON?

Comment: The result `<61737369 616e2e6e 65742f73 65637572 652f7072` looks like the output of logging `NSData` and those are hex codes. The first few represent the text "assian.net/secure/"

Comment: Interesting. Good to know that the information is there, just encoded in hexidecimal. I really don't understand why I get that format here, but JSON if I make the same request from JMeter.

Comment: You are getting back an `NDData` object. That's what you logged. The data could be text or it could be JSON (which is just specially formatted text).

Comment: When I paste the whole response into a hes to string converter it give me the json string that I am looking for, so it is the correct response, just encoded into hex.

Comment: No, it just looks that way when you log it. Use `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` to convert the `NSData` object to an array or dictionary containing the JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `Content-Type` header, but you don't appear to be sending any content. It seems more like you should be setting the `Accept` header.

You can't log an `NSData` instance and expect to see the contents, even if the content is a string. When you log, either try to convert the data into a string (`alloc, initWithData:`) or deserialize the JSON (`JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`).